# How to setup ssl based communication in a Unix/Linux message queue?

Tags: linux, unix, linux-kernel

I am planning to use Unix message queue for one of my application in Unix. But I don’t have any idea how to implement ssl based communication between my application and Unix message queue. Can anyone please help me on this?

Comment: https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/6930/how-is-a-message-queue-implemented-in-the-linux-kernel

Comment: Hi user1506104, I already red that. But my problem is not with creating the message queue but how to make it ssl base communication.

Comment: Please don't ask for a tutorial. You should ask a specific question for a particular programming problem. Since Stack Overflow hides the Close reason from you: *"Questions asking us to recommend or find a book, tool, software library, tutorial or other off-site resource are off-topic for Stack Overflow as they tend to attract opinionated answers and spam. Instead, describe the problem and what has been done so far to solve it."*

Answer (score 1):

What you're trying to do, is to implement DTLS in SysV IPC rather than BSD Sockets.

You can do this by taking an existing implementation (never roll your own crypto), replace every instance of read/write and recv/send, with msgrcv/msgsnd, and adapt the arguments passed to the functions.